# How do I make my header wider?

Tags: html, css

I have designed a header for my webpage which uses three `li`'s, however my menu needs to become a bit wider in order for it to look better. Right now my code is like this:

```css
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    animation-name: dropHeader;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 0.75s
}

header ul {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="mobile-menu-close">
        <span>Close</span> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
   <!-- Not sure if to menu or not -->

   <ul id="menu" class="shadow">
        <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</header>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to reach the "corners" of the webpage without messing up across different resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex css` to achieve this.

```css
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    animation-name: dropHeader;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 0.75s
}

header ul {
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="mobile-menu-close">
        <span>Close</span> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
   <!-- Not sure if to menu or not -->

   <ul id="menu" class="shadow">
        <li>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</header>
```

You can also use `justify-content: space-between;` to fit with full screen. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me but it moved the text to the far left despite the fact that I specified that the text should be text-align: center;

Comment: My pleasure.... For width please check this https://jsfiddle.net/k4e1jv8w/

Answer (score 0):

Try this out... 
This works for both large screens as well as small screen displays.

Here is the changed CSS code...

```
/*start css*/
header {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
    animation-name: dropHeader;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

header ul {
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header li {
    list-style: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

header li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}
header li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
/*end css*/
```

No change in your html code...

```
<!--start html-->
<header>
<div id="mobile-menu-close">
    <span>Close</span> <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<!-- Not sure if to menu or not -->

<ul id="menu" class="shadow">
     <li>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul> 
</header>
<!--end html-->
```

You can do the remaining necessary changes.
I hope this answer satisfies your question.